# Is it good practice to use HttpStatusCode for application errors?

Tags: c#, httpclient

We are currently in the process of rebuilding the internal company structure and are talking to a supplier (of a machine) who offers a Http-based interface (if we pay of course). I am not allowed to disclose too much but the interface is supposed to perform an action and it's possible that this action might fail for various reasons. I'll give an example

```
public HttpResponseMessage MoveItem(int item, string option)
```

Now this cause can either succeed or fail for (example) 3 reasons:

- Succeed: It worked, the machine is in the state I want it to be
- Reason A: The machine was currently performing an operation
- Reason B: The item was unavailable
- Reason C: Another issue occurred

Now the supplier offered the following return values for this function call:

- Succeed: HttpStatusCode.OK
- Reason A: HttpStatusCode.Conflict (409)
- Reason B: HttpStatusCode.NoContent (204)
- Reason C: HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError (500)

Each of those would be accompanied by a human readable message.

Now I have a feeling that this is kind of a strange approach. For my understanding (and please correct me if I'm wrong!), it appears that our supplier is actually mis-using Http status codes for application-side errors. If it was for me, I would actually always throw an exception if the call fails and provide a detailed info within that exception. Yet, I have to admin that I haven't worked with HttpClient until today so my knowledge is kind of limited at the moment (this will change, no worries).

As for the main question: is our supplier's approach considered good practice nowadays with the use of HttpClient and is our supplier right or is my feeling right and this seems a little like mis-using Http code as application error codes?

Comment: Learn about REST APIs.

Comment: _" I would actually always throw an exception if the call fails and provide a detailed info within that exception"_ - but then everything is a 500 response and you have to parse it to find if it's Reason A, B, etc.

Comment: Isn't it possible to throw "different" exceptions, e.g. a CurrentlyBusyException() (just an example)?

Comment: I'm just trying to get an understanding if the approach provided by our supplier is "common" and "correct" :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you throw an exception everything comes back to the caller as a 500 and the only way to distinguish why the error occurred is by parsing the error message. That's not a great way to handle things. By sending back different HTTP status codes the calling application can take action based on the feedback from the service. For example, if you get back a 409 you might wait a few seconds and try again, whereas if you get back a 500 there's no point in trying again.

My one potential beef would be that they used 204 instead of 404 to indicate that something was not found, but that's assuming that "item was unavailable" is the same thing as "item was not found/located." I may be misunderstanding the semantics of "unavailable" in which case my comment would be moot.

**UPDATE**

Comments and other posts talk about "hijacking" the error codes. If this were a true REST implementation I would agree. But it's not. It's more of an RPC call. Quite frankly, the vast majority of so-called "REST" APIs that I've encountered are simply JSON-over-HTTP (i.e. basically SOAP without the ceremony and substituting JSON for XML).

Given all that, the vendor's implementation seems fine to me. They are using discrete codes to indicate the status of the operation. As long as those codes remain consistent from release to release it's effectively the same thing. Any argument beyond that is academic and a matter of personal preference (vague warnings about how "it will cause problems the further you go into the project" notwithstanding).

Comment: "they" used 204? Who are "they"? The illuminati?!

Comment: @DavidG They, as in the company mentioned in the question. Don't be obtuse.

Comment: Craig, so you're basically saying that this is REST-conform and the usual approach? Don't mind the exact message, it was only meant as an example. It's just I haven't come across this topic yet and wanted to get an opinion.

Comment: Partial agree, but *"the only way to distinguish why the error occurred is by parsing the error message"*. Usually I json encode my Exception and return that json with `500`. That exception should be in a shared dll and can easily be deserialized.

Comment: "parsing the error message" that makes it sound like addressing the details of an exception is more burdensome, or less efficient than addressing the http status code.  And getting a 500 does not mean there is no point in trying again, it just means you need to decide, based on the application's internal failure codes, on what to do next.  As this is a machine being talked to through http, for its own internal errors, it should provide its own codes, not try to hijack the transfer protocol error codes.

Comment: Agapwlesu: This is exactly what I've been thinking. I am wondering if using Http Error codes for "something that sounds somewhat similar but is not really related to HTTP at all" is typically used. I have the feeling that using HttpStatus codes is just kind of a shortcut.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, Do you throw and catch the exception, then serialize it, or just instantiate the exception and serialize it? I'm assuming that in the exception is some kind of code/enum that indicates the cause of the error? If any of that is true, why not just bypass that extra work and find a status code that reasonably represents what you're trying to convey?

Comment: I throw a `MachineIsBusyException`, and handle it at the end of the request pipe (In webapi for example a `HandleErrorAttribute`) using serialization @CraigW.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, fair enough. Now the caller needs to have access to that type to deserialize it, and if you're throwing different types the only way really to do that is to try deserializing it into each well-known type until you succeed. That works great when you control both sides of the communication (we use that technique for some of our system-to-system communications) but it doesn't work so well when you don't control the external system (which may not even be written in .NET and relying on a .NET specific class like Exception won't work anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Using http codes to indicate the type of error is common, but using codes other than 5xx to indicate problems within the server is not.

In general, my inclination on the specifics aligns with yours, that their error codes are suspect.

It's difficult to say for sure without more internal details, and a lot of decisions around http return codes are judgement calls, so I can't give a definitive correct answer here. That said, I compared your descriptions to those in [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) :

- Reason A: The machine was currently performing an operation

If "currently performing an operation" means an operation on the same resource, and this creates some sort of conflict, then 409 seems like it appropriate to me. If the machine is simply busy, that would sound like exactly what 503 is supposed to indicate.

> #### 10.5.4 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD handle the response as it would for a 500 response.
>
> #### 10.4.10 409 Conflict
>
> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be possible and is not required.
>
> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For example, if versioning were being used and the entity being PUT included changes to a resource which conflict with those made by an earlier (third-party) request, the server might use the 409 response to indicate that it can't complete the request. In this case, the response entity would likely contain a list of the differences between the two versions in a format defined by the response Content-Type.

- Reason B: The item was unavailable

A 204 might be adequate if the server wants to indicate that a request succeeded, but there was nothing found. If unavailability is a temporary situation, I would think a 5xx or 3xx might be more appropriate, since 5xx can indicate a temporary (internal) problem, and 3xx indicated the client needs to take additional action.

> #### 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.
>
> #### 10.3 Redirection 3xx
>
> This class of status code indicates that further action needs to be taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request. The action required MAY be carried out by the user agent without interaction with the user if and only if the method used in the second request is GET or HEAD. A client SHOULD detect infinite redirection loops, since such loops generate network traffic for each redirection.

- Reason C: Another issue occurred
  This looks legit. 500 is often used as a catch-all for "some sort of problem we didn't think to handle".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that this way of doing things is kind of kludgy.  The http status codes are designed for the http resources, that is for handling the status of the request for a resource, not for passing back the status of some physical machine being controlled by that resource.  It is the status of the transport mechanism.  Because of that, they are going to be using some codes to mean things they are not meant for.  If your client application consumes those codes the way they are using them, then I guess it works, but it is definitely a kludgy way of doing things, and it will cause problems the further you go into the project.

I would, like you, send back a custom exception and detail the problem in that exception.  Some comments objected to having to drill down into the exception to get the actual error data.  But that is a non-issue.  The client application would basically be getting a success or fail, and on fail, the details of that fail.  It's not like getting the details of an exception is any less inefficient than getting a status code.

Comment: How would you encode such errors inside the response? I want to have a unique error code plus maybe an additional status message but I don't want to use Http Errorcodes just because the wording sounds the same like the application error (Not found could mean to me: "I didn't find the resource, the actual URL" but also "I didn't find the item"). I'd never be able to distinguish between those two in my application if I get the idea right.